# Why does Psycopg2 return list of tuples in with Stored Procedure?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, psycopg2

I have been using Psycopg2 to read stored procedures from Postgres successfully and getting a nice tuple returned, which has been easy to deal with. For example...

```
    def authenticate(user, password):
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=MyDB host=localhost port=5433 user=postgres password=mypwd")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        retrieved_pwd = None
        retrieved_userid = None
        retrieved_user = None
        retrieved_teamname = None
        cur.execute("""
                    select "email", "password", "userid", "teamname"
                    from "RegisteredUsers"
                    where "email" = '%s'
                    """ % user)
        for row in cur:
            print row
```

The row that prints would give me ('user@gmail.com                                    ', '84894531656894hashedpassword5161651165                ', 36, 'test                                              ')

However, when I run the following code to read a row of fixtures with a Stored Procedure, I get (what looks to me like) an unholy mess.

```
    def get_from_sql(userid):
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=MyDB host=localhost port=5433 user=postgres password=pwd")
        fixture_cursor = conn.cursor()
        callproc_params = [userid]
        fixture_cursor.execute("select sppresentedfixtures(%s)", callproc_params)
    for row in fixture_cursor:
        print row
```

The resulting output:

('(5,"2015-08-28 21:00:00","2015-08-20 08:00:00","2015-08-25 17:00:00","Team                                  ",,"Team                                     ",,"Final                                             ")',)

I have researched the cursor class and cannot understand why it outputs like this for a stored procedure. When executing within Postgres, the output is in a perfect Tuple. Using Psycopg2 adds onto the tuple and I don't understand why?

How do I change this so I get a tidy tuple? What am I not understanding about the request that I am making that gives me this result?

I have tried the callproc function and get an equally unhelpful output. Any thoughts on this would be great.

Comment: You'll have to post the pl/pgsql function. For all we know, your pl/pgsql function could be converting the row to a string.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sppresentedfixtures(useridentity integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
select "Fixtures"."Fixture_No","Fixtures"."Fixture_Date","Fixtures"."Opening_Date","Fixtures"."Closing_Date","Fixtures"."Home_Side","Predictions"."Home_Side_Score","Fixtures"."Away_Side","Predictions"."Away_Side_Score","Fixtures"."Fixture_Stage"
from "Fixtures"
left join "Predictions"
on "Predictions"."Fixture_No" = "Fixtures"."Fixture_No" and "Predictions"."userid" = useridentity
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION sppresentedfixtures(integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're `SELECT`ing the result of the function directly. Your function returns a set of things, and each "thing" happens to be a tuple, so you're getting a list of stringified tuples back. What you want is this:

```
SELECT * FROM sppresentedfixtures(...)
```

But this doesn't work, because you'll get the error:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

The solution is to return a table instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sppresentedfixtures(useridentity integer) RETURNS TABLE(
  Fixture_No int,
  Fixture_Date timestamp,
  ...
) AS
$BODY$
  select
    "Fixtures"."Fixture_No",
    "Fixtures"."Fixture_Date",
    ...
  from "Fixtures" ...
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql
```

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful and I will give that a try!

Just to help my understanding, why is it that in Postgres when I run the query "select sppresentedfixtures(30)" I get a clean tuple. But using psycopg2 gives me a different result? At the end of the day is it not just the same stored procedure?

Comment: @LemusThelroy My guess would be psql has the ability to deal with `record` types, while psycopg2 does not.

Comment: Your suggestion worked and I think I understand why it wasn't working from your explanation so thank you again